# Problem with Android Studio App Inspector

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, app-inspection

I've been trying to view my app inspector, but it keeps saying I need a device with an API level 26 or higher. How can I tell what version I'm using now and how can I upgrade it? ( I use the android emulator ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new emulator. When you're creating one (through android studio) you get to choose what API version you want. Most emulator version are backwards compatible, so choosing the newest one probably won't be an issue. Android comes out with new versions all the time (unlike apple), so this is a common issue.

You could also download an emulator outside of studio. These will usually allow you to choose between different levels at will, but they aren't always great. If you have you're own android, that's usually best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the API level of a connected device or emulator:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```